# The Stack Overflow Labs page on Developer Sentiment on AI/ML uses non-unique HTML element IDs

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-labs

This is the page: https://stackoverflow.co/labs/developer-sentiment-ai-ml

For example, the ID `h3-professional-developers-and-country` is used three times. Now I can't link to sections properly. Attempts to use `h3-professional-developers-and-country` as a URL fragment will only link to the first element with that ID.

Fix please?